# Fire a function on the change event of an already changed select

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, onchange

I have a form with three select fields. I want the second select to populate based off of the first selection and then the third to populate based on the second selection. 
So property type -> County -> City. A basic idea of my js is as follows.

```
$('.property_type').change(function(){
if(this.value == 'com'){
    $('.property_detail_county').html('MY HTML');
}else if((this.value == 'res')){
    $('.property_detail_county').html('MORE HTML');

}
```

All of this is in the .ready(). And this is working fine. My problem is, when you try to write the second function that is made to populate the second select(the cities), it doesn't fire anything. Here is my second function, also inside of the ready.

```
$('.property_detail_county').change(function(){
console.log('Changed');
```

});

My theory is that the second function is never getting read or loaded because of the condition. Do you guys know of another way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

P.s. If this has already been answered, feel free to just point me in the right direction, I couldn't find the subject anywhere.

Comment: The change event is triggered when a user choose a value, not when you change the content of your select !

Comment: yea what is .property_detail_county a select input or just some div? if you need to trigger change on a select after altering its value with js then use trigger()

Comment: You will need to trigger the `.change()` event manually when you change the value of the second option programmatically.  `.change()` isn't called when you change the value with code unless you use code to specifically trigger it.

Comment: You may be looking for something like [this](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-related-selects/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the HTML that you put in the 2nd dropdown. For example, if the HTML is like:

```
<div id="a"><select>...</select></div>

<div id="b">...</div>
```

And your javascript does this:

```
if(this.value == 'com'){
    $('.property_detail_county').html('<select>...</select>');
}
```

You have replaced the 2nd select statement completely and there is no change even tied to it. The change even is tied to the old `<select>` that you replaced.

You can just reinstate the change code:

```
if(this.value == 'com'){
    $('#b').html('<select id="sel_b">...</select>');
    $("#sel_b").click(function() {
        ... the stuff to do when 2nd one is clicked ...
    }
}
```

It really works better if you define a function to handle that second set of stuff.

*Note* There are other ways to do this where you detect the change event as it bubbles up to a `<div>` or some element higher up the DOM tree. You can read about that in the jQuery docs. It's called "event delegation".